# Using transparent png files in activex image

Tags: excel, vba

Currently i am working on excel vba based printing program.I need only certain cells(not areas) to be a print object.I know excel does not have such a function.So i thought using a png image that has transparent background.My reason to do this making active x image non printable.Active X image does not allow me to use png files.
Do i need special codes to allow me to use png images?

Comment: ActiveX image? or ActiveX object? If object, just uncheck the `Print Object` option. `Right click on control > Format Control > Properties`

Comment: I need to insert active x image on sheet with transparent background(png file).So i can set print object to false,therefore print anything behind transparent areas.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got it right (sorry) but why don't you just insert the png image through the Insert>Image? and then uncheck its "Print object" property?

Comment: Well i did not know that :) After reading your comment i tried and solve my problem.Thanks for the help.